# How to remove special character in id and title?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

i want the result as

`id =Afghanistan`

`title=AF`

inside bracket it gave the non english characters.how to solve it

```
(

    {
    id = "Afghanistan (\U0627\U0641\U063a\U0627\U0646\U0633\U062a\U0627\U0646)";
    title = "AF\n   \n";
},
    {
    id = "Albania (Shqip\U00ebria)";
    title = "AL\n   \n";
},
    {
    id = "Algeria (\U0627\U0644\U062c\U0632\U0627\U0626\U0631)";
    title = "DZ\n   \n";
},
    {
    id = "American Samoa";
    title = "AS\n   \n";
}

)
```

Comment: this is an xml parser result please anyone

Answer (score 0):

It'll make everything easier if you can make sure that everything after a opening bracket can be removed.

```
// find the location of the bracket
NSInteger bracketStart = [str rangeOfString:@"("].location;
// get the substring to the opening bracket
NSString *reducedStr = [str substringToIndex:bracketStart];
// remove whitespace at the end of the needed string
reducedStr = [reducedStr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

and you can remove the newlines from your countrycode like this:

```
NSString *countryCode = [@"AF\n   \n" stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* id_str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: "Afghanistan (\u0627\u0641\u063a\u0627\u0646\u0633\u062a\u0627\u0646)\0"];
id_str = [[id_str componentsSeparatedByString: @"("] objectAtIndex: 0];

NSString* title = @"AS\n   \n";
title = [title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: @"\n "]];
```

Comment: while i add it to the array it gave the result as with quotes.

Comment: i removed all brackets substring and  now i want to only remove ""

Comment: NSString* str = [@"\"Hello\"" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\"" withString: @""];